# Usage of article while separated from noun

Tags: nouns, articles

Folks, being non-native speaker, came across a phrase, and trying to figure out correctness:

**An** Options Regulations Records Request has been issued by our company for your Firm.

Should or should not be an article that is in bold fonts?
And if it should,  what would it be?

Comment: Articles, like all determiners, go before adjectives that go before nouns. So that is the correct position. Why would you think it is not?

Comment: @JohnLawler - my thinking was/is: it either should not exists at all, or to be "A" since, technically, article refers  to "Request"

Comment: Don't worry about what "article technically refers to". An article doesn't refer to anything; technically, articles don't refer. Time enough for subtlety after you learn when to use them in basic sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An** is correct because the first letter of the next word is a vowel sound. It does not necessarily have to be an actual vowel.

The word "hour" for instance does not start with a vowel, but with a vowel sound (since you don't pronounce the "H").

The next 3 R's don't really matter when it comes to determining what article to use.

So unless you're referring to a specific request, in which case you could use "The Options Regulations Record Request that has been issued by your company for your firm [...]" you have to go with "an". You would use "a" if the word request stood alone as the word request starts with a consonant sound.

I'm not entirely certain what you mean by "separated from noun" though. If you're not please with this please clarify.

Comment: if you are mentioning "...The object and the next 3 R's don't really matter to determine what article to use...." then the Article should be "A", is it not?

Comment: Yeah, I edited that. Was a little hard to understand. I meant that it doesn't make a difference that the noun itself is "Request". What kind of article you use is determined by the sound of the first letter of the word that comes after the article (In your case, "Options"). It doesn't even matter that it's a noun for that matter.